# JobScheduler - What happens to periodic jobs when app is killed?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

the title pretty much says it all. How do jobs scheduled by the JobScheduler behave once the app is killed? I want to schedule a periodic job that should only run when the app is either in foreground or background, but should stop executing once the app was killed. Is the JobScheduler API the right way to do this or does it behave like the AlarmManager and executes scheduled jobs even if the app was killed?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an app is force stopped, all its periodic jobs will be cancelled as well. I found out with the awesome adb command `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` which displays a lot of useful information about active jobs, history and much more.